# How to use element of the array in query like

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-like

I need to use an array of elements in query in jQuery. My query is:

```
"SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `Tags` LIKE CONCAT('%', ',', ('" + id + "'), ',', '%')"
```

Where `id` is an dynamic array, so I basically need:

```
"SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `Tags` LIKE CONCAT('%', ',', ('" + id[0] + "'), ',', '%') **OR LIKE id[1] OR LIKE id[2]**..."
```

if I'll use a `forEach` loop, it will return rows depending only on one of the elements in array, it is not support Like .. Or Like .. logic

```js
var idArr = id.split(",");
idArr.forEach(function (id) {
     _runQuery("SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `Tags` LIKE CONCAT('%', ',', '" + id + "', ',', '%')", function (rows) {....}
```

Comment: Is this query run against a database or this is another flavour of JavaScript framework?

Answer (score 1):

Given an array

```
var id = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Try this

```
 " WHERE tags LIKE '%"+ id.join("%' OR tags LIKE '%")+'%');
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/XzXnf/

Answer (score -1):

The simplest answer to your question is: Tags should probably be a separate table, then you would have:

"SELECT * from projects as p join tags as t on t.project_id = p.id where t.tag in (id[0], id[1], id[2]....)"

Of course, you can generate the required id string via a join easily enough (id.join(", ") will probably do it.

Alternatively, as @codingbiz points out, you can use a more complex id.join() call to expand the required OR's, but there are limits to that approach, and this is about as complex a query as you can reasonably make before normalising starts to look like a really good idea.

Comment: My concern is this doesn't look JavaScript-Specific. In what framework is writing SQL statement like this in JavaScript is encouraged or praticed?

Comment: I share your concern. I am assuming this is a nodejs server-side application, and the jquery tag is erroneous. If this is being done client-side, I shudder.

Comment: Thank you, I generate a 2 strings  and then add them to the select, but using join looks more elegant

Comment: So, why is it tagged jQuery? As far as I can tell, there is nothing jQuery specific here.